# Position of text filled by jinja

Tags: python, jinja2, spacy

I am generating documents from templates in order to get training data for Spacy. These templates are processed by jinja. I am happy enough with the output, and now I want to generate annotations for Spacy.

Each template has a few places that are filled by jinja, and I need to know, in the rendered text, the positions and labels of text that was filled in by Jinja. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Share your code where you you have attempted to achieve this.

Comment: I'm not sure what I can add. I can call the render function on a template and a context, and I get a str back. What I would need is some kind of intermediate state where I can know what part of the output string comes from jinja.